# Display two listings with different lines in same height

Tags: listings, height

I'm trying to display two listings side-by-side. I accomplished this using minipage:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[title=Bad]
some bad code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[title=Good]
some good code
and another good code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

In this example, the left one displays one line and the right one displays two lines, so the height of two listings are not same.

[image: example]

Is it possible to make the shorter one get same height of longer one, so that I can get the result like:?

[image: expected result]

Comment: Define `same height`, please. Where does the shorter one begin and where does it end?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Added some images for more specific description. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem as posted. @ChristianHupfer, do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: @patryk.beza: See a possible solution

Comment: It seems that [it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373794/44382) doesn't work with [xetex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX): *Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex.*

Comment: @patryk.beza: Please learn how to address somebody here -- you've done it already. Better post such comments below the relevant answer, and no, you did **not** mention that you're using `xelatex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `tcbraster` and `raster equal height`, the options to `tcbraster` are given to the underlying `tcblisting` environments, local options are possible there, as usual, with `tcolorbox`.

In case `lualatex` or `xelatex` are used, make sure to add `listing options={}` in order to remove the default `tcblatex` style which loads `inputenc`.

The number of boxes in a row can be set with `raster columns=2`, for example, of course this depends on the specific needs, since `listings` usually do not use text lines that wrap around, more than `2` columns is not recommended.

Please note that there must be nothing else than `tcolorbox` environments wrapped in the outer `tcbraster` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height,enhanced, sharp corners,listing only,colbacktitle={yellow},coltitle=black,colback=white,boxrule=1pt]
\begin{tcblisting}{title=Bad}
some bad code
\end{tcblisting}
\begin{tcblisting}{title=Good}
some good code
and another good code
\end{tcblisting}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]